# Gem installed, but not found by Ruby?

Tags: bash, ssh, capistrano

I have the following Capistrano snippet:

```
namespace :bundle do
    task :install do
        run "gem list && bundle -v"
    end
end
```

When I run

```
cap bundle:install
```

I get the following output:

```
 ** [out :: ....compute-1.amazonaws.com]
 ** [out :: ....compute-1.amazonaws.com] *** LOCAL GEMS ***
 ** [out :: ....compute-1.amazonaws.com]
 ** [out :: ....compute-1.amazonaws.com]
 ** [out :: ....compute-1.amazonaws.com] bundler (1.3.4)
 ** [out :: ....compute-1.amazonaws.com] rake (10.0.3)
 ** [out :: ....compute-1.amazonaws.com] rubygems-bundler (1.1.1)
 ** [out :: ....compute-1.amazonaws.com] rvm (1.11.3.6)
 ** [out :: ....compute-1.amazonaws.com]
 ** [out :: ....compute-1.amazonaws.com] ERROR: Gem bundler is not installed, run `gem install bundler` first.
```

gem is showing bundler is installed, but when I try to run bundle -v, I get a contradicting error saying it's not? I don't understand why?

The other thing I tried was to login to the server via terminal, when I run bundle -v there, it works fine?

Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: The problem is that my .rvm paths are not defined, not sure where .rvm paths are defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get my script working by adding some environment variables:

```
set :default_environment, {
    :PATH => "/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@my_gemset/bin:" +
        "/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/bin:" +
        "/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin:" +
        "/home/ubuntu/.rvm/bin:" +
        "/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
    :RUBY_VERSION => 'ruby-1.9.2-p320',
    :GEM_HOME => '/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@my_gemset',
    :GEM_PATH => '/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@my_gemset:/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

do you use [rvm-capistrano gem](https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm-capistrano)? It will load RVM for you.

Comment: Not using rvm-capistrano at all. I've got a bash script I wrote that checks the rvm version, installs my rubies, gemsets and does bundle install etc.